# Xcode Entitlements don't appear enabled with CMake

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I'm generating an Xcode iOS project from CMake, and am connecting the entitlements file like so:

```
set_target_properties(TargetApp PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/TargetApp.entitlements")
```

And this is working well during compiling/signing/running, however the Xcode IDE does not seem to be able to see the things enabled (at least from the GUI point of view)

TargetApp.entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>REDACTED</string>
    </array>
    <key>inter-app-audio</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

but once I configure the Xcode project, they do not appear "turned on"
[image: Xcode showing entitlements turned off]

Any ideas on how to get CMake to convince Xcode these entitlements exist?

Comment: Just double checking... you run `cmake -G Xcode ..` for example to produce the Xcode file, right?

Comment: yes that is correct, so I have an xcodeproject, then when I open it, it builds etc correctly, but the "Capabilities" tab shows all gray like this screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, this is only a GUI problem. CMake does not generate the project settings that cause this to work, but the compiler picks it up just fine.